# Subtracting Enum elements in groovy

Tags: groovy, enums

Let's assume we have an enum:

```
enum MyEnum
{
   ONE, TWO
}
```

we can easily subtract MyEnum values from each other by using:

```
def a = MyEnum.values()
println (a - MyEnum.values()) //results: []
```

but if we try to use strong typing, we don't receive an empty list:

```
Collection<MyEnum> a = MyEnum.values()
println (a - MyEnum.values()) //results: [ONE, TWO]
```

What type should we use to properly subtract MyEnum values and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the return type of `E.values()` is `E[]` the obvious answer
would be

```
MyEnum[] a = MyEnum.values()
```

The way how two arrays are "subtracted" is defined in
`org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods`:

```
public static <T> T[] minus(T[] self, Object[] removeMe) {
```

But if you are using something "collection-y" this is used (e.g. for a `Set` here):

```
public static <T> Set<T> minus(Set<T> self, Object removeMe)
```

(Only the given *element* is about to be removed - not each element).

So if you want something "collection-y", then you also have to turn the
array into something iterable or "collection-y".  E.g. this works also:

```
Set<MyEnum> a = MyEnum.values()
println (a - MyEnum.values().toList())
// → []
```

And if you want to be explicit you might as well use a function like
`removeAll`.